# Will ArcGIS model written in version 10.2.2 work with ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

Will an ArcGIS model written in version 10.2.2 work on an instance of 10.1 desktop?

I suppose it would be somewhat dependent on the features in the model and whether they were available in the earlier version of ArcGIS.  Either way, is there some way to export the model to an earlier version to test it and see if it works?

Answer (score 2):

> Will an ArcGIS model written in version 10.2.2 work on an instance of 10.1 desktop?

Maybe.  Yes it will depend on whether the functionality is available in the earlier version, but also whether anything has changed within each tool between the versions.  If nothing has changed then it *should* work.

> Either way, is there some way to export the model to an earlier version to test it and see if it works?

Yes and No.  You can't export the model on its own, however you can right-click on the *Toolbox* in ArcToolbox that your model is stored in, select Save As, and select the Save-As type for whichever version you're wanting to back-save as.

[image]

If you are wanting only the single model, you'd need to create a new empty Toolbox and copy your model into it before using the Save As option for saving to previous version.

Comment: Actually, looking at my screenshot it appears that 10.1 and 10.2 (and 10.2.2) may be considered the same so could be worth just taking a copy of your Toolbox and loading it on your 10.1 machine and giving it a try.  The screenshot was taken in 10.3.1 so it may be a different option in your 10.2.2